# CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL "Null"

Tags: null

I'm using following line to create a PDF reference:

```
CGPDFDocumentRef thePDFDocRef = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL(filePath);
```

On my simulator, this is working. But when I deploy this to my device, the call returns "null"

The filePath is exactly the same. As a test, I'm also printing if the filePath (PDF) exists and it does.

I also checked for case sensitive things. My device is running iOS 6.1.2 and I'm testing with Simulator 6.0.

Any ideas?